# ColdFusion 2016 - Security service not available

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

CF 2016 on windows10 with IIS

I've checked other threads on similar issues and they don't appear to apply. 
My laptop has needed to be crash-started on a number of occasions recently due to the laptop not waking up from sleep mode. A couple of times ColdFusion 2016 didn't start automatically and needed to be manually started. Now, ColdFusion appears to be starting automatically, but now I'm getting an error:

> HTTP Error 500.0 - The Security service is not available.

I'm afraid I have no idea where to start on this or even what additional information to provide. So, I would really appreciate any hints.

The remainder of the error has the following information:

> Detailed Error Information:
>
> Module:      IsapiModule   Notification:  ExecuteRequestHandler
>
> Handler:     ISAPI-dll
>
> Error Code:  0x00000000
>
> Requested URL:    http://zbay_sys:80/jakarta/isapi_redirect.dll
>   Physical Path : C:\ColdFusion2016\config\wsconfig\1\isapi_redirect.dll
>
> Logon Method: Anonymous
>
> Logon User    :   Anonymous

I really hope I don't have to re-install CF

Comment: You note repeatedly that you are running ColdFusion 11, but the error message refers to the ColdFusion connector in ColdFusion 2016. Are you running both on the same computer?

Comment: Ah sorry, my mistake. Have corrected the OP. No other versions are running simultaneously.

Comment: I've reinstalled ColdFusion. Was reasonably painless. Problem now gone.

Answer (score 1):

Glad, that you are sorted.

The error message says, "The Security service is not available." Thus IIS is showing http based error 500. If the service is not starting, there could likely be a problem at ColdFusion end.

Please try the following, if you face the similar issue in future:–

1. Stop ColdFusion service (if not already)
2. Launch Command prompt as Administrator
3. Browse to cf_root\cfusion\bin and run the following
   command **coldfusion.exe -start console**
4. Try to access the CF Admin, once the services are started.

In case it gives an error message, please share the same.