# Security service not avaiable ColdFusion 2016

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I have fresh installed ColdFusion 2016 on my mac with built in web server.(No IIS/Apache). I followed the normal installation procedure.
Just after installation when i hit to the server (http://127.0.0.1:8500/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm) everything seems to working fine.

Once i restarted my mac today morning, after that I am getting an error

`500 The security service is not available`

I checked this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36393202/coldfusion-2016-security-service-not-available) but no success. I am getting this error when i hit to cfadmin or any normal cfm page.

[image]

Comment: Could you check cf16 application service is run or not on your Mac?

Comment: Can you serve up other pages? Perhaps http://127.0.0.1

Comment: @cfprabhu: Yes the server is running. No , I am not able server any other pages also.